# Nginx autostart on Docker (ubuntu:trusty image)

Tags: 14.04, nginx, autostart, docker

I have installed nginx to Docker container (container from ubuntu:trusty image).
And every time when I call `docker stop nginx` and after `docker start nginx`, my nginx server in shut down state.

1. How autostart/stop nginx on `docker start/stop` command?
2. How I can see logs for commands, that executed on start and stop container? `dmesg` is empty.

Sorry, I think I don't understand the root of the problem, and making bad steps.
I tried to fix it using:

- add `service nginx start` to `/etc/rc.local` file, before `exit 0`
- create file `nginx.conf` containing

  ```
  description "Nginx"
  author "Me"
  start on filesystem and started docker.io
  stop on runlevel [!2345]
  respawn
  script
    /usr/bin/docker start -a nginx
  end script
  ```

But nothing to help.

Comment: Command `init-checkconf nginx.conf` returns this answer  `ERROR: version of /sbin/initctl too old`